# How do I update entire checklists using Trello API and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, list, api, trello

I would like to update entire checklists at one time using the Trello API.  I can successfully update an individual checkItem by using their

Trello API - PUT URI (updates single checkitem in a checklist on a card)

```
/1/cards/[card id or shortlink]/checklist/[idChecklist]/checkItem/[idCheckItem]/state
```

Is there a way to do this without looping through each checkitem on the checklist and calling the PUT for each item to update the state?

I'm working in an Underscore.JS, Handlebars.JS, and jQuery/AJAX application.